# Unable to run lessc on Ubuntu 13.04. Not even a "command not found"

Tags: node.js, shell, ubuntu, less, npm

I installed less with
    sudo npm install -g less

Here are the last 10 lines of output:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
/usr/bin/lessc -> /usr/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
less@1.4.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/less
├── mime@1.2.9
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── ycssmin@1.0.1
└── request@2.21.0 (json-stringify-safe@4.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, qs@0.6.5, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, cookie-jar@0.3.0, node-uuid@1.4.0, hawk@0.13.1, form-data@0.0.8, http-signature@0.9.11)
```

Browed here a bit and figured maybe those warnings weren't the issue.  Seemed all well and good, except when I run lessc without parameters it just kicks me back to the command prompt.  Unusual as lesscss.org states this should list options.
Same behavior when I try a command like

```
lessc less/style.less > css/style.css
```

Just kicks me back to the command line as if I never tried to execute anything.  Expected a "command not found" at the very least.  style.css remains uncompiled.

**Background**: I'm recently new to Ubuntu after a lot of time on OS X.  I was used to LiveReload, but I still haven't wrapped my head around [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload)  I figured I wouldn't mind doing some manual compiling for a little while.

**Update:** I started from scratch and built from source. Instructions to build from source: https://gist.github.com/dwayne/2983873 lessc works fine now after reinstalling from npm.  I feel like I must have had some sort of conflict via apt-get somehow.

Comment: Does `lessc --help` print anything?

Comment: Does this file exist? /usr/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc

Comment: Sorry for the painfully slow reply @nFreeze. Yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered this in the past and solved it by adding a symlink to a directory on my path:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc /usr/local/bin/lessc
```

I see you've worked around your issue, but someone else may find this information useful.